# How to create custom placeholders for Asset Modules file naming in my own Webpack5 image loader plugin?

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I'm developing my own Sharp-based image loader in Webpack5 where I can convert the format and resize the input image. My goal is the create some new placeholders like **[width]**, **[height]**, **[newext]** (*the final converted format*) that could be used outside in my Webpack config like this:

```js
{
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|webp|avif|tiff)$/i,
  type: 'asset',
  generator: {
    filename: '[name]-[width]-[hash].[newext]'
  }
}
```

...but I can't find any related documentation after 2 days of browsing the [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/) and searching on Google.
Now I'm afraid that's not even possible yet. Is it...? Thank you.

Edit:
It seems that it is not possible, and my [feature request](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/14851) on GitHub was rejected.